# Need Help: Animation - Button Click -> Back and Forth, Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
$(targetElement).animate({
    marginLeft: "+=250px"
}, {
    duration: speed,
    complete: function () {
        targetElement.animate({
            marginLeft: "-=250px"
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function () {
                animatethis(targetElement, speed);
            }
        });
    }
});
};

animatethis($('#q1'), 1000);
```

I need a button where you press it, and the loop will go once. Just like an attack animation, where I press a button and the image will attack an other image.

Comment: Your callback is triggering the animate function again so looks like this will just keep looping.

Comment: And the function call should just be animatethis("#q1" , 1000) since you already have the $() in the function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go man.... let me know if you have any questions!

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6SkPM/4/)

```
// Animation Function
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {    
    $(targetElement).animate({"margin-left" : "+=50px"}, speed, function(speed){
        $(this).animate({"margin-left" : "-=50px"}, speed);
    }); 
};

//Animation Trigger
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(){
    animatethis('#q1', 250);
});
```